# Angular : script tags generated before html tag

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app served on `localhost:4200` with `ng serve`.
When I hit `localhost:4200/home`, everything works fine.
When I hit `localhost:4200/vehicle/idKind/id`, Chrome tries to load `localhost:4200/vehicle/idKind/runtime.js`, which results in a 404 error.
After inspecting the `index.html` generated by angular cli, I noticed the script tags are generated before the html tag :

```html
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- some scripts, stylesheets and fonts -->
    <title>My app</title>

</head>
<app-root></app-root>

</html>
```

When I place them manually after the `<head>` (and the `<base href="/" />`) Chrome tries to load `localhost:4200/runtime.js`, which is the behaviour I want.

My `src/index.html` :

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- some scripts, stylesheets and fonts -->
    <title>My app</title>

</head>
<app-root></app-root>

</html>
```

Why are my scripts tags generated before html?

Comment: can you show your routes configurations

Comment: There. I updated the problem to fit with my real routes

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug on a blank new project

Comment: Got it, the scripts tags are generated before the html tag in index.html, don't know how to fix it though

Comment: you can move those scripts inside head tag

Comment: How? They don't appear in `src/index.html`

Comment: can you show your index.html, in your inspected index.html body tag is missing, app-root should be inside body tag

Comment: Haha I forgot the body tag indeed. Please write the answer so I can accept it

Comment: can you also attach the index.html along with inspected one, that you were using earlier to the question to know what exactly caused this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you probably need to check if app-root selector is written inside body like this in index.html

```html
<body>
     <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: I was having the same problem Wrapping my <app-root></app-root> in the body tag solved it. Thank you!